# Remix, prisma, Postgres, querying the database FATAL: sorry, too many clients already

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, limit, prisma, remix.run

Ok, so i got in to this problem running query in my app based on:

- Remix app framework
- Postgres as a db
- Prisma as ORM

I have simple loader function, which basically loads post types from my db.

So, after i hit browser reload button for a couple of times i get this error

> Error querying the database: db error: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already

The only one way is get rid of error is restart the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In development Remix purges the require cache before each request. This is to support `LiveReload`

You need to store the Prisma client on the global object to survive the purge.

You’ll see an example of this on the Jokes tutorial.

https://github.com/remix-run/examples/blob/main/jokes/app/utils/db.server.ts

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple, we should init our prisma client before the render starts.

To do this, [follow the remix guideline](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/tutorials/jokes#connect-to-the-database).

This way it will reuse object after server update.

---

Second thing you need to do is to increase your connection limit, by passing number to connect url in this way:

postgresql://postgres:@localhost:5432/db?connection_limit=13

The number is:

> (Quantity of cores on your computer * 2) + 1

To get more info about optimizing prisma connection pull, [follow](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/connection-management).